# Что(-)таки ты такого сделал?

Tags: дефис

Нужен дефис?

> Что(-)таки ты такого сделал?

> Ты как(-)таки это сделал?

> Где(-)таки он?

> Про кого(-)таки ты говорите?

> Чьё(-)таки это бельё?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Что ты **все-таки** такого сделал?*

*Ты как **все-таки** это сделал?*

*Где **все-таки** он?*

*Про кого **все-таки** ты говоришь?*

*Чьё **все-таки** это бельё?*

**Пояснение**

1. В приведенных примерах разговорную частицу ***ТАКИ*** следует заменить нейтральной по стилю частицей ***ВСЕ-ТАКИ***. Иначе речь получается невнятной и неблагозвучной (по **фонетике**).

Кроме того, **нет оснований** для употребления частицы ***ТАКИ***,  которая должна выражать дополнительные **смысловые оттенки.**

2. **Раздельное** написание: *что таки, как таки, где таки,  про кого таки, чье таки.* Сравнить: ***так-таки*** (слово есть в словаре).

**Из Нацкорпуса:**

*— Лохи это, а не охрана, им стало интересно знать, **что таки** случилось, и они себе пошли смотреть телевизор...*

— *Что ты, батюшка! **Где-таки** ребенку служить! До вечера не выдержит.* (Старая орфография, 1841 год.)

*Вся политика министерства сельского хозяйства — **как таки** не дать крестьянину земли.*

*Мозги штурмует, дочка, не знаю, **чьи таки** мозги.*

**Примечание.** Примеров с частицей ***ТАКИ*** не много, при этом ее использование во всех случаях выглядит **обоснованно**. В современной речи это обычно связано с **иронией**, в том числе в **публицистическом** стиле.